# How to refresh an activity over GCM Listener Service

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have got a little problem with refreshing an Activity. I have added GCM Listener Service to my app. Its Listener Service should make my activity to refresh when it gets "messege" from GCM Service. I don't want to build a notification. Also I don't want to refresh my activity periodically with Timer().

There are codes:

MyGcmListenerService.java

```
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    String theme = data.getString("theme");
    sendNotification(message,theme);
}

private void sendNotification(String message, String theme) {
    Messages mess = new Messages();
    mess.message=message;
    //what I have to do here to make my FirstLayout.java refresh?
}
```

FirstLayout.java

```
package com.notif.rasulbek.notifyme;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;



public class FirstLayout extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView mes;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_layout);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstMes);
```

I want to replace following lines:

```
        Timer autoUpdate = new Timer();
        autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mes.setText(Messages.message);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 2000);
      }//this approach doesn't like me :(

}
```

Again, I want to send a thing like signal, from MyGcmListenerService.java, which refreshes my Activity. Please anyone help me with this problem. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest ways to do this is to use the [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to send a broadcast then use a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), in your activity, to listen for the broadcast. Once the listener "hears" the broadcast it can trigger the necessary update to the activity.

You can see [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java#L74) sample application that updates an activity when it is registered with GCM.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to implement this. One is quite similar to what @Arthur has mentioned I am expanding that concept further using set of different API's.

- In `onReceive` method of the GCMIntentService call `displayMessage` which has the code to Broadcast a message when a GCM notification is received.
- In the `MainActivity's` *onCreate* register a receiver to address this Broadcasted message.
- Finally the *onReceive* of the BroadcastReceiver would update the I using the `mHandleMessageReceiver` call.

Another simpler method is to update the UI in the onResume directly with a Boolean variable. Rest of the idiology would be same as above strategy where you listen for the Broadcast when the GCM notification is received and send it to update the UI.

Here is a Sample code:

```
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    update = true;;
}

protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

   update = false;
}
```

Make sure that the `update` Boolean is static/global.

Comment: Hi AniV, thanks very much for your answer. But, unfortunately it is not working. To be more specific `mes.setText()` can not get `Message.message` variable when it is changed by `MyGcmListenerService`